# Disable gestures in parent custom control in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, gesture-recognition, skiasharp

I have a custom control "container" to manage gestures and a Skiasharp drawable control inside. The functionality I'm looking for is, in the first step the user can make zoom/move the image inside the container, then the gestures of the container are disabled and the user can draw in the visible image with the fingers. It used to work months ago, but when moved to xamarin 3.x it started to fail.

This is the code of the container

```
public class GestureContainer : ContentView
{
    private const double MIN_SCALE = 1;
    private const double MAX_SCALE = 4;
    private double startScale, currentScale;
    private double startX, startY;
    private double xOffset, yOffset;

    private PanGestureRecognizer pan;
    private PinchGestureRecognizer pinchGesture;
    private TapGestureRecognizer tap;

    public static readonly BindableProperty GestureOnProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create("GestureOn", typeof(bool), typeof(GestureContainer), defaultValue: true, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: GestureOnChanges);

    public bool GestureOn
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(GestureOnProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GestureOnProperty, value);
        }
    }


    private static void GestureOnChanges(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        GestureContainer gestureContainer = bindable as GestureContainer;

        if ((bool)newvalue)
            gestureContainer.SetGestures();
        else
            gestureContainer.GestureRecognizers.Clear();

    }


    public GestureContainer()
    {
        pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pan = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        tap = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 2 };

        SetGestures();

        Scale = MIN_SCALE;
        TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
    }

    private void SetGestures()
    {
        pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);

        pan.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pan);

        tap.Tapped += OnTapped;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);
    }

    private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       /**/
    }

    void RestoreScaleValues()
    {
        /**/
    }

    void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
       /**/
    }

    void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
       /**/
    }
}
```

The part with the "weird" function is this:

```
gestureContainer.GestureRecognizers.Clear();
```

When I launch the binded property to false, the method is called, the .Clear() is called, but no matter what the pinch/pan/tap are still working, and that makes the drawing touch not to work correctly

**EDIT**

This is the XAML code

```
<controls:GestureContainer GestureOn="{Binding OptionsVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}}"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <controls:GestureContainer.Content>
                    <Grid>
                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage  
                            Rotation="{Binding Rotation}"  
                            x:Name="originalView"
                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                            DownsampleToViewSize="True"
                            Source="{Binding Imagen.ImageStream}"/>
                        <Grid IsEnabled="{Binding OptionsVisibility}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <controls:BindableSKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                                       Color="{Binding StrokeColor}"
                                       WidthStroke="{Binding StrokeWidth}"
                                       EnableTouchEvents="True"
                                       PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />
                            <Grid.Effects>
                                <skiacontrols:TouchEffect Capture="True" TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
                            </Grid.Effects>
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </controls:GestureContainer.Content>
            </controls:GestureContainer>
```

Comment: Do you mean that in xamarin 3.x it not work?

Comment: Yes, the only changes I made was moving from VS2015 to VS2017 and from Xamarin.Forms 2.X to 3.4

Comment: Can I know what version of XF you are working with?

Comment: I have 3.5.0.169047

Comment: To be honest there are a lot of bugs in 3.5 and when I say a lot I mean a lot can you check with the last stable version of 3.4?

Comment: Try using `if(null == pinchGesture){pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();}if(null == pan ){pan = new PanGestureRecognizer();}if(null == tap ){tap =new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 2 };}` to make sure that the `pinchGesture` & `pan` & `tap` be the Single instance in method `GestureContainer`.

Comment: Ok... I can confirm moving back to 3.0.0.446417 makes it work again... :-(

Comment: I was trying versions and the one who brokes the functionallity is 3.2.0.839982 I will change it to 3.1 and find what the problem is in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It seems multiple reference being created.

try to write a function like this

```
void clearGesture() {
  pinchGesture.PinchUpdated -= OnPinchUpdated;
  pan.PanUpdated -= OnPanUpdated;
  tap.Tapped -= OnTapped;
}
```

And call this explicitly like, `gestureContainer.clearGesture();`

Comment: Even though I had already tried something like that, I tried it again, but it still fails

Comment: Can you share some demo code? How and from where you are loading the contentView?

Answer (score 0):

**Points I think you missed:**

- Using `nameof(PropertyName)` in place of `"PropertyName"` since it helps us ignore human error's eg: Spelling mistakes.
- Calling the OnPropertyChanged Method in the setter to make sure you do not miss the PropertyChanged event.
- Calling the base class implementation on constructors, just to make sure everything works perfectly.(Just sort of habit, i do not think this as mandatory)

Hence I have made the necessary changes and they can be found below I have changed them and they can found below:

```
 public class GestureContainer : ContentView   
 {
    private const double MIN_SCALE = 1;
    private const double MAX_SCALE = 4;
    private double startScale, currentScale;
    private double startX, startY;
    private double xOffset, yOffset;

    private PanGestureRecognizer pan;
    private PinchGestureRecognizer pinchGesture;
    private TapGestureRecognizer tap;

    public static readonly BindableProperty GestureOnProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(nameof(GestureOn), typeof(bool), typeof(GestureContainer),
           defaultValue: true, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: GestureOnChanges);

    private static void GestureOnChanges(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        GestureContainer gestureContainer = bindable as GestureContainer;

        if ((bool)newValue)
        {
            gestureContainer.SetGestures();
        }
        else
        {
            gestureContainer.GestureRecognizers.Clear();
        }
    }

    public bool GestureOn
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(GestureOnProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GestureOnProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GestureOn));
        }
    }

    public GestureContainer() : base()
    {
        pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pan = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        tap = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 2 };

        SetGestures();

        Scale = MIN_SCALE;
        TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
    }

    private void SetGestures()
    {
        pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);

        pan.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pan);

        tap.Tapped += OnTapped;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);
    }

    private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /**/
    }

    private void RestoreScaleValues()
    {
        /**/
    }

    private void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        /**/
    }

    private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        /**/
    }
}
```